# Unity Door open with "e"?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I would like to be able to open my Gate with "e". I've got to the point where the player has to stand in front of the Gate and then you have to press "e", but I don't know how to do it. So far I've written that

```
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) 
{
    if(other.CompareTag("Player") && Input.GetKeyDown("e"))
    {
        Debug.Log("door opens");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Pretty unlike that you manage to press the key down exactly in the same frame the trigger enter is called ;)

Answer (score 3):

As `OnTriggerEnter` is only called the single frame the player collides with the door, instead use [`OnTriggerStay`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnTriggerStay.html). The other option would be to store whether or not you have collided with the door then detecting the input in `Update` instead.

If you use `OnTriggerStay`:

```
private void OnTriggerStay(Collider other) 
{
    if(other.CompareTag("Player") && Input.GetKeyDown("e"))
    {
        Debug.Log("door opens");
    }
}
```

If you would like to use `OnTriggerEnter` still, I would also use `OnTriggerExit` to know when they are no longer colliding with it.

```
private bool touchingDoor = false;

private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) 
{
    if(other.CompareTag("Player"))
    {
        touchingDoor = true;
    }
}

private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other) 
{
    if(other.CompareTag("Player"))
    {
        touchingDoor = false;
    }
}

private void Update()
{
    if(Input.GetKeyDown("e") && touchingDoor)
    {
        Debug.Log("door opens");   
    }
}
```